# Importing CSV file into 2D String array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have to read a text file into a 2d Array.

The only problem I am having, is the width of the array varies, with a maximum size of 9 columns.
I don't know how many rows there will be.

Some lines will have 6 columns for example, and some will have 9.

here is a small section of my CSV file:

```
1908,Souths,Easts,Souths,Cumberland,Y,14,12,4000
1909,Souths,Balmain,Souths,Wests,N
1910,Newtown,Souths,Newtown,Wests,Y,4,4,14000
1911,Easts,Glebe,Glebe,Balmain,Y,11,8,20000
1912,Easts,Glebe,Easts,Wests,N
1913,Easts,Newtown,Easts,Wests,N
```

and here is my code so far

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        readData();

    }

    public static void readData() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader dataBR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("nrldata.txt")));
        String line = "";

        ArrayList<String[]> dataArr = new ArrayList<String[]>(); //An ArrayList is used because I don't know how many records are in the file.

        while ((line = dataBR.readLine()) != null) { // Read a single line from the file until there are no more lines to read

            String[] club = new String[9]; // Each club has 3 fields, so we need room for the 3 tokens.

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // For each token in the line that we've read:
                String[] value = line.split(",", 9);                
                club[i] = value[i]; // Place the token into the 'i'th "column"
            }

            dataArr.add(club); // Add the "club" info to the list of clubs.
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.size(); i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dataArr.get(i).length; x++) {
                System.out.printf("dataArr[%d][%d]: ", i, x);
                System.out.println(dataArr.get(i)[x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at ass2.readData(ass2.java:23)
at ass2.main(ass2.java:7)
```

Can someone please help :'(

Thank you!

Comment: Which is line 49 of your code? Also, you should move the line `String[] value = line.split(",", 9);` to be before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your inner loop. You are trying to access 9 elements of `value` regardless of how many values there are on the line. First, you should move the assignment to `value` to be before the inner loop. Then, you need to limit the loop iterations to the minimum of 9 and the length of `value`:

```
String[] value = line.split(",", 9);                
int n = Math.min(value.length, data.length);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // For each token in the line that we've read:
    data[i] = value[i]; // Place the token into the 'i'th "column"
}
```

Note that the trailing elements of `data` will be `null`.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the "minimum" part, since you pass '9' as the second argument to `split()`.

Comment: @ExpertSystem - That's true. It's kind of a belt-and-suspenders thing, in case the code evolves and `data` somehow ends up being possibly shorter than 9 (perhaps inadvertently). A symbolic constant would be better here rather than having the literal `9` scattered all over the code.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for read the CSV file.

```
// Read all
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File("nrldata.txt")));
List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();

// Convert to 2D array
String[][] dataArr = new String[list.size()][];
dataArr = list.toArray(dataArr);
```

Comment: This makes things really easy, I like this better than the accepted answer.

Comment: what should we import?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error, because you try to access a 7th token (index 6) on a line that contains only 6. Replace that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // For each token in the line that we've read:
    String[] value = line.split(",", 9);                
    data[i] = value[i]; // Place the token into the 'i'th "column"
}
```

with this:

```
String[] value = line.spkit(",", 9);   // Split the line into max. 9 tokens
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    data[i] = value[i];   // Add each token to data[]
}
```

You could, in fact, replace the whole `while-loop` body with this one-liner:

```
dataArr.add(Arrays.copyOf(line.split(",", 9), 9));
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/uN16oK)**.

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer! Nice one @gkalpak

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array, you can use `ArrayList` of `List`. As List is dynamically growable so you do't need to think of it size either.

```
List<List<String>> dataArr = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

and

```
while ((line = dataBR.readLine()) != null){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
            dataArr.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(",", 9)));                
}
```

Comment: thats not a solution for ArrayIndexOutofBound, still if he uses wrong index, he may still end up getting same exception

Comment: I have proposed a better solution, I think you got me wrong :)